Move one status to another doesn't work in Kanban View of Case
in salesforce, i set up a kanban view for case by status, when i move the case to a different status, it doesn't saved. it changed back to the original status. And each time when i move the case, there is a case window popuped. how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Are their any validation rules that may be blocking the status change?
I tried your scenario above; we have validation rules that require a case type and subtype be entered prior to change of status -
When there is no type entered on the case I attempt to move in kanban, the case opens and displays an error message about the type/subtype being required, and the case will not reposition in kanban view.
